# Wiremock returns 200 OK response even if transformer not found

Tags: wiremock, wiremock-standalone

If I accidentally make a typo in stub definition JSON and transformer name doesn't match I still get a 200 response. It's unexpected and is a problem. Is there any way to make Wiremock to fail or at least log that transformer was not found?

I'm using wiremock-standalone version 2.35.0.

Answer (score 2):

There's currently no way to make WireMock return or log an error in this case.

You could submit a PR / raise an issue here: https://github.com/wiremock/wiremock